# directory is write protected even after executing chmod

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, yii2

I followed the instructions here (https://serverfault.com/questions/310325/how-do-i-give-a-user-access-to-var-www-html) to create a group of webadmin, add my own username (ubuntu) to this list and then change the permissions of my folder /var/www/html:

```
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www/html
```

Now when I list the directories, they show as having write privileges for groups e.g.:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-96:/var/www/html/yiisimple/basic$ ls -l
total 104
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar  1 06:22 assets
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar  1 06:22 commands
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  1639 Mar  1 06:22 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 31799 May  6 17:10 composer.lock
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 May  6 19:51 config
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 May  6 19:53 controllers
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  1622 Mar  1 06:22 LICENSE.md
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Mar  1 06:22 mail
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 May  6 19:51 models
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  2699 Mar  1 06:22 README.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  5049 Mar  1 06:22 requirements.php
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root  4096 May  6 20:07 runtime
drwxrwxr-x  3 root root  4096 Mar  1 06:22 tests
drwxrwxr-x 11 root root  4096 May  6 17:10 vendor
drwxrwxr-x  5 root root  4096 May  6 20:02 views
drwxrwxr-x  4 root root  4096 Mar  1 06:22 web
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root root   697 Mar  1 06:22 yii
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   515 Mar  1 06:22 yii.bat
```

but if I try to so much as save a single file, Ubuntu blocks me with "`directory is write protected`" message. Also, I am doing this because I'm trying to use the Gii code generator, and it also seems to be blocked by this write protection.

So more general question:

What's the appropriate way to add my username ubuntu to a group so I have write privileges on my web server's /var/www/html folder?

And more specific question

What's the best way to set this up for Yii? Any particular tricks of the trade I should know about?

thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your permissions are fine but the owner and group should not be root. Usually Apache runs using the *www-data* user. So you should also change the owner and group of the folders

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/yiisimple/basic
```

This should enable *gii* to work properly. Now for you to have access, the best is to add yourself to the *www-data* group.

```
sudo adduser your_user_name www-data
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this can help someone.
I had solved my problem of uploading file on my centos 7 web server.

Try this

```
# sudo chown apache:apache -R /var/www/html/ppdb2019/files
# cd /var/www/html/ppdb2019/files
# find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
# find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
# sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/ppdb2019/files -R
# sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/ppdb2019/files -R
```

Here is the [source code](https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/#comment-3494)